# Elastic index/search_analyzer match all tokens

Tags: elasticsearch

In my mapping file for ElasticSearch, for `"all"`, I have `index_analyzer` and `search_analyzer`:

```
{
  "all": {
    "enabled" : true,
    "index_analyzer" : "index_analyzer",
    "search_analyzer" : "search_analyzer"
  }
}
```

If I search `"foo bar"` on `all`, it returns hits for `foo` `OR` `bar`. How would I make this `AND` by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of [Match Query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html)

The default match query is of type boolean. It means that the text provided is analyzed and the analysis process constructs a boolean query from the provided text. The operator flag can be set to or or and to control the boolean clauses (defaults to or). The minimum number of should clauses to match can be set using the minimum_should_match parameter.

[...]

Here is an example when providing additional parameters (note the slight change in structure, message is the field name):

```
{
    "match" : {
        "message" : {
            "query" : "this is a test",
            "operator" : "and"
        }
    }
}
```